# Processing large downloads with Spray

Tags: scala, spray

I'd like to GET a potentially large file with Spray and process it incrementally, rather than loading the whole response entity into memory at once. (Specifically, to process a CSV file line by line.) The request will be to an arbitrary server, so I can't expect a chunked response. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. If you set `spray.can.client.parsing.incoming-auto-chunking-threshold-size` to some finite value, entities bigger than that will be delivered in chunks. See here: https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-can/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L372

Comment: @jrudolph That's exactly what I was looking for. It should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `spray.can.client.parsing.incoming-auto-chunking-threshold-size` to some finite value, entities bigger than that will be delivered in chunks. See here: https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-can/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L372

See this ticket for an overview of features wrt chunked and streaming facilities in spray: https://github.com/spray/spray/issues/281